# C# Mediaelement stops showing after 1 week of runtime

Tags: c#, windows, mediaelement

i am heavily in trouble with a kiosk Software written in C#.net V6 WPF running on an Win10 1906 IOT machine. (VS2022)

On the main screen i am showing a Mediaelement dynamically loaded with .mp4 files.

This works fine.

Unfortunly ... after a week... the mediaelement is not showing any graphics any more.
I get no exception. So the code continues to work....

Even when i am restarting my application it is not showing anymore.
Restarting windows fixes that temporary ... (for a week, then it happens again).

So i think it somethings wrong on the operating system side but i have no clue....

Memory remains stable at the same level all the time. (500MB)

Code behind:

Snipplet of media loading:

```
                    case 3:
                        myImagePoettinger.Source = new Uri(@"Graphics\door_open.mp4", UriKind.Relative);
                        repeatVideo = false;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        myImagePoettinger.Source = new Uri(@"Graphics\insertion.mp4", UriKind.Relative);
                        repeatVideo = false;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        myImagePoettinger.Source = new Uri(@"Graphics\Start_2.mp4", UriKind.Relative);
                        repeatVideo = false;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        myImagePoettinger.Source = new Uri(@"Graphics\door_close.mp4", UriKind.Relative);
                        repeatVideo = false;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        myImagePoettinger.Source = new Uri(@"Graphics\hydraulic.mp4", UriKind.Relative);
                        repeatVideo = true;
                        break;
                    case 8:
```

Snipplet of Replay funktion (Event on Media Ended):

```
        void Media_Ended(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (repeatVideo)
            {
                myImagePoettinger.Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
            }         

        }
```

WPF Call of the Media Element

```
<MediaElement x:Name="myImagePoettinger" Width="900" Height="600" Visibility="Visible"></MediaElement>
```

Thank you for your help.

I am sorry if i am missing some important Infos ... please just ask.

Comment: It sounds like some kind of handle leak. Are you able to run e.g. Process Explorer on the same machine a few days apart and able to compare the number of open handles?

Comment: Yeah... i could do so... currently the machine is running in its faulty state. The Number of Handles is about 51000. Compared to a freshly started machine with the same image it is nearly the same with about 49000 handles.